# how to update specific record in duplicate records in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table in MySQL database. which is having 3 records shown below.
The table :

| columns | name | address | phone | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st record | raj | Chennai | 232329 | null |
| 2nd record | raj | Chennai | 232329 | null |
| 3rd record | raj | Chennai | 232329 | null |

I want to update comments column as duplicate records for two records only.
The output should be like this....
The table

| columns | name | address | phone | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st record | raj | Chennai | 232329 | duplicate records |
| 2nd record | raj | Chennai | 232329 | duplicate records |
| 3rd record | raj | Chennai | 232329 | null |

pls tell me how to do this in MySQL.

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the comments column for all-but-one of your duplicate records? How will you know which record is the "real" one and which are duplicates? It will help if you show us your table definition. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: all records are same in my table. I want to update all records as duplicates except one, because that one I want to move to main table.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows :

First, we need to most recent record for each group:

```
select name, address, phone, max(id) as id
from mytable
group by name, address, phone
having count(*) > 1
```

Then we use `left join` to identify all records except the latest id of that group :

```
update mytable t
left join (
  select name, address, phone, max(id) as id
  from mytable
  group by name, address, phone
  having count(*) > 1
) as s on s.name = t.name and s.address = t.address and s.id = t.id
set t.comments = 'duplicate records'
where s.id is null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3lX0X_55)

Comment: when I executed this query in mysql ide workbench, it returns an error that "unknown column 'id' in the field list"

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET comments = 'duplicate records'
WHERE (name, address, phone) IN (
SELECT name, address, phone
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name, address, phone
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: This query will update all records as duplicate records, I want to update all duplicate records except one record.

Comment: try this UPDATE your_table
SET comments = 'duplicate records'
WHERE (name, address, phone) IN (
  SELECT name, address, phone
  FROM (
    SELECT name, address, phone, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, address, phone ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM your_table
  ) AS subquery
  WHERE rn > 1
);